# Flutter add dash after every 3 number textfield input and limit number of figure input

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I'm looking for a way to add ( - ) after every number input in flutter textformfield and to limit the number of input to just 9 figure. For example 145-123-234. I will appreciate if anyone can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I install this [flutter_masked_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text)

And imported the library to my input page, changed my `TextFormField` controller to `MaskedTextController _controllerCode = MaskedTextController(mask: '000-000-000');` then parse `_controllerCode` to `controller` in the `TextFormField` and finally my `Widget` looks like below:

````
  MaskedTextController _controller = MaskedTextController(mask: '000-000-000');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'e.g. 101-234-190',
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [mask text formatter package](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter) sample usage:

```html
 var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(
      mask: '+# (###) ###-##-##', filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')});
      
   TextField(
                      inputFormatters: [ maskFormatter],
                      autoFocus: false,
                      inputType: TextInputType.phone,
                      inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

us input formatters:

**inputFormatters: [                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9,-]')),
LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(9),
],**

this may help you number of input digits will work fine and regex expression for dash after 3 will change in your case in your case may change.